# Headers or what?

Tags: angularjs, http-post

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

my code

```
.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (UserName, Password, callback) {

            /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
             ----------------------------------------------
            $timeout(function () {
                var response = { success: UserName === 'test' && Password === 'test' };
                if (!response.success) {
                    response.message = 'UserName or Password is incorrect';
                }
                callback(response);
            }, 1000);

            */


            /* Use this for real authentication
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://216.0.1.209/AuthenticateUser',
                data: {
                    UserName: 'UserName',
                    Password: 'Password'
                    },
                headers: {
                    'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001'
                        }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
            });

        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (UserName, Password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(UserName + ':' + Password);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    UserName: UserName,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic';
        };

        return service;
    }])
```

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and IE, give same result "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."..

Warm regars.. Thanks for any help or advice

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will throw this error when your `javascript` is sending request to a different domain.

To temporarily work around this issue during development, you can use [chrome extension](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwixsfHehNXSAhWML48KHV2TDgkQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fallow-control-allow-origi%2Fnlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHSUFqc6ylxfxfbWzmmFJ6L5QUvyg&bvm=bv.149397726,d.c2I) to suppress your browser warning.

For production environment, if your javascript has different domain from your API server, you will need to whitelist your javascript domain on your API server.

Different languages used on server have different ways of allowing this, google `[language] CORS` will get you some examples. The domain name to be allowed must match the URL from the error message, including protocol `http/https` and whether there is a trailing slash or not.

Note: using `*` is not recommended unless your API are meant to be requested by public users.